# Azure Logic App: How to download email attachments

Tags: azure, email-attachments, azure-logic-apps

I have logic App that triggers on arriving of the email and passes attachment to Azure Function for further processing.

Here How it looks now
[image]

So, it reads the email and passes the attachemnts to the Function.
Function is developed with C#

Is it possible to get attachment content like a stream or download it inside of the function?

Thank You

Comment: what do you get in the attachments at the moment ? I think logic app download file as base64 encoded string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Download the image to a blob storage account.
2. Process the image (stream) in a function that is either trigger by blob creation or eventgrid-trigger.